# Add Restriction in Protege

Tags: owl, semantic-web, protege, restriction

I would like to add restrictions to the values that individuals of a particular class can take via an object property.

For example, I have the classes `GPS` and `Means` (contains instances `Spoofing`, `Jamming`, `Speed_Change`, `Sign_Change`) connected by the object property `HasMeans`:

GPS -----> <sub>HasMeans</sub> Means

I want to ensure that any instance of the class `GPS` can only connect to the `Means` class instances`Jamming` and `Spoofing` and not the others. 
If I say `GPS` instance `G1` `HasMeans` `Speed_Change`, my objective is to classify this as an error when I run the reasoner.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following OWL2 capabilities:

- [universal quantification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Universal_Quantification)
- [enumeration of individuals](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Enumeration_of_Individuals)
- [individual inequality](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/#Individual_Inequality)

In the [Manchester Syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/#Quick_Reference) used in Protégé:

```
Prefix: : <https://stackoverflow.com/q/50004546/7879193#>

Ontology: <https://stackoverflow.com/q/50004546/7879193>

Class: GPS
    SubClassOf: hasMean only {jamming, spoofing}

Class: Mean

ObjectProperty: hasMean
    Domain: GPS
    Range: Mean

Individual: gps1
    Types: GPS
    Facts: hasMean jamming, hasMean spoofing

Individual: gps2
    Types: GPS
    Facts: hasMean spoofing, hasMean speed_change

DifferentIndividuals: 
    jamming, spoofing, speed_change

Individual: jamming
    Types: Mean 

Individual: spoofing
   Types: Mean

Individual: speed_change
   Types:  Mean
```

This is how inconsistency explanation looks like:

[image: Laconic inconsistency explanation screenshot]

Comment: Hello again, thank you for your answer.
I have put
HasMeans only {Jamming} in the class expression editor.
However, the problem still persists, what I want is for the Protege reasoner to give me an error when I try to add the fact that gps1 hasMeans speed_change. But that is no the case, instead it just adds the restriction to the fact much like the hasValue Restriction.

Comment: @ArunaMaulik, have you added the `DifferentIndividuals` axiom (*Edit > Make all individuals different*)?

Comment: @StanislavKralin Yes i did. I just restarted Protege to make sure everything was fine and it worked! not for the first time has restarting protege helped..Thanks again!

Comment: @ArunavaMaulik Instead of restarting you should "synchronize the reasoner" next time. You always have to do this once you changed the ontology in order to force the reasoner to recompute inferences.